# Opening spyder causes periodic ping spikes every 10 seconds

Tags: python, anaconda, ping, python-3.5, spyder

I have been having an issue lately, where I have periodic ping spikes to my internet being caused just by opening the `spyder` program, and which disappear as soon as i close python.

Tested: in command prompt `ping google.com -t` and every 10 seconds the ping spikes from 3-5 ms to 500-1500ms, and back to normal for 9 seconds, and repeats. These stop immediately after I close python.

I have tried many other solutions to this, as many people reported periodic ping spikes - but so far none seem to have it being caused by just opening spyder.

Does anyone know the cause, and a possible solution to this?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I can reproduce this (but for me the max spike goes to 500ms). However, I don't know how to fix it. Sorry to ask, but why is this a problem to you?

Comment: I do game beta testing and development,  and occasionally use python to assist me, as well as with automating some functions for testing etc. Hence why ping spikes cause me issues sometimes. I also use it more for physics simulations, hence why I mainly use the anaconda package. The spikes do not affect me when I'm working offline, just for game testing

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll ask around and come to you if I know something else about this problem.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, much appreciated